# How to load 1TB file into a DB using google cloud functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

Let's say I have thousands of 1TB file that need to be inserted into a database. These files are stored in Google Cloud Storage. How could I create a function that would save these files to my database? My understanding was that Cloud Functions have a size limit of 2GB (memory), so what would be the way to 'stream' the data from GCS, through the Cloud Function, into my database. Here is how I would normally do this:

```
with open('1TBFile.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        self.cursor.execute('insert into mytable''')
```

How would I do this in Cloud Functions -- to 'get the file' onto my local system, or the equivalent. Here is an example where it seems to get the file as a blob to process it: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/imagemagick/main.py.

Comment: The fragment you quote should not have more than one line in your file at a time in memory, so it shouldn't matter how big the actual file is?  I am thinking your cloud  function ought to be able to read the file from cloud storage, using code like the one you quote, no?

Comment: @moilejter I guess my question is, how would I access the "1TBFile.csv" in the first place if it's stored in GCS? The above code treats the file as if it's local, do Google Cloud Functions have 'local-like' access to Cloud Storage objects? If so, how would the above be re-written to reference a file in a bucket?

Comment: What and where is the database you want to import this data in? Is it a CloudSQL instance? An on-premises db?

Comment: Have you considered the google cloud storage libraries https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

Comment: @SoulMan -- sure that would work. Could you please show me how I'd use that?